# Is this Terminal command safe to run on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, shell

I was trying to install a virtual machine on my Mac, and I followed the directions in an article from Digital Trends.  I have since found additional resources, which have made me concerned about a step in the original instructions that said to type this into the Mac terminal:

```
curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | bash
```

I initially trusted this code because I thought Digital Trends was safe, but is this code safe?

Answer (score 2):

You're running whatever the contents of that URL are as your current user.

For certain definitions of safe, sure, this is fine, as it won't influence other users of your machine.  I'd still take a look at the code in the URL to see if it's doing something you'd approve of doing yourself.

In your specific case, it appears to be a boring install of Microsoft binaries, so if you trust Microsoft to not do anything stupid/dangerous to your machine (I don't), you're likely fine.

Comment: My instinct would be to split this single command into two commands to guarantee that what's inspected is what's performed. The contents of a remote URL can change in an instant, and running this as a single command places trust entirely within the hands of whoever controls the contents at that URL. I assume the command was provided this way for the sake of simplicity. Perhaps the URL owner is completely trustworthy, and the script at that URL never changes. But bad results can come from malicious acts, simple typos, and bugs. Those who can review a shell script before execution should do so.

Comment: I've removed the VM.  How do I undo this code?

Comment: @user1695929 open that url and follow the steps in reverse.  it's likely just a matter of "clean," and not anything dangerous.  e.g. remove the .ievms dir and its contents in your home directory, uninstall 'unar' if you don't want it, remove the ie vm from virtualbox, etc.